# TOMCAT Eclipse Localhost call webservice SOAP rpc TLS 1.2

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, soap, tls1.2

I'm trying to call to webservice through soap-2.3.1.jar with the next code:

```
        SOAPMappingRegistry smr = new SOAPMappingRegistry();
    Call call = new Call();
    call.setSOAPMappingRegistry(smr);
    call.setTargetObjectURI("urn:mensajeriaCIBERPAC");
    call.setMethodName("procesaMensajeRecibido");
    call.setEncodingStyleURI(encodingStyleURI);
    Vector params = new Vector();
    params.addElement(new Parameter("Mensaje", String.class, xml_doc, null));
    call.setParams(params);
    Response resp = null;
    try {
        resp = call.invoke(url, "");
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the server needs TLSvs1.1 or v1.2. I receive handshake error

```
faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure]
```

. We need to test in local.

Any help?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `Error opening socket: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException'`, perhaps you forgot the `s` in `https`. Just saying.

Comment: Also, [this one](https://portal2portal.blogspot.com.ar/2016/03/error-handshakefailure-seen-when.html) could help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using eclipse and localhost. Is it possible?

Comment: I added this code

Comment: <Connector port="8443" 

 maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
 keystoreFile="C:\Users\amaroto\.keystore" keystorePass="giglon.com"
 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" />

Comment: and now it's working with ssl, but the request is not in tlsv1.2

Comment: How do you know it's not in TLS1.2 ? Add -Djavax.net.ssl=debug system property to your client and come back with the log.